# Output urls containing some words from a string to another string java

Tags: java, string, parsing, url

I have a string containing several urls. I want to retrieve the urls containing "thistext" and copy them into another variable named "outputlinks". This is my code.

```
  String links = "http://www.website1.com/thistext  
                  http://www.website1.com/othertext
                  http://www.website1.com/thistext";


  String outputlinks =""; // ??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant:

```
String links = "http://www.website1.com/thistext\n" + 
               "http://www.website1.com/othertext\n" +
               "http://www.website1.com/thistext";
```

Then you can do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String links = "http://www.website1.com/thistext\n" + 
                   "http://www.website1.com/othertext\n" +
                   "http://www.website1.com/thistext";
    String[] linksArray = links.split("\n");

    for (String link : linksArray) {
        if (link.contains("thistext")) {
            System.out.println(link);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all use a good separator for your links, like commah, semi colon or something else. Use a string tokenizer to get the individual links and finally search for your term, i.e "thisText" in each of the tokenized strings, using `indexOf`. That will get the job done for you.